# org.hibernate.QueryException with arithmetic operator in Where clause

Tags: hibernate, hql

I'm tring to make a simple arithmetic operation between two columns.

my HQL request is: `SELECT a.ht+a.tva FROM com.test.entity.TestTable a`

I'm using `Hibernate 3.6.10-Final`, And i have this error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: , expected in SELECT [SELECT a.ht+a.tva FROM com.test.entity.TestTable a]
  org.hibernate.hql.classic.SelectParser.token(SelectParser.java:203)
  org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClauseParser.token(ClauseParser.java:109)
  org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClauseParser.end(ClauseParser.java:136)
  org.hibernate.hql.classic.PreprocessingParser.end(PreprocessingParser.java:145)
  org.hibernate.hql.classic.ParserHelper.parse(ParserHelper.java:52)
  org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:240)
  org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:209)
  org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
  org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
  org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:124)
  org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
  org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
  org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1770)
```

But in jboss doc chapter 16.7, it says:

> you can use arithmetic operators, concatenation, and recognized SQL functions in the select clause:
>
> ```
> select cat.weight + sum(kitten.weight)
> from Cat cat
> join cat.kittens kitten
> group by cat.id, cat.weight
> ```

i have tried with `cast( ... as Long )` but didn't work too.

Anybody has a solution or a recommendation ?

Thanks a lot,
Yann Terzibachian

Comment: reference is wrong : arithmetic operator are supported with aggregate functions : chapter 16.7 http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-aggregation  Did you try `SELECT a.ht+a.tva FROM com.test.entity.TestTable a group by a.id` (assuming id is your pk)

Comment: Same error with a group by on my pk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved!
Just a problem in my persistence.xml,

i used this property:

```
property name="hibernate.query.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory"
```

But only `org.hibernate.hql.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory` provide hibernate 3 functionalities

Thanks a lot